# Can I use a Surface Pro Signature cover (keyboard+touchpad) with a desktop computer?

Tags: keyboard, touchpad, microsoft-surface, microsoft-surface-pro, microsoft-surface-pro-4

Over the past 8 years I've been working exclusively on a Macbook laptop, and I really think it feels ergonomically much better to have the small form factor keyboard + a good touchpad at the center than the "traditional" keyboard and mouse combo.

Now I've changed jobs, and they require that I use a Windows desktop computer, which I don't mind except for the ergonomical change of having to go back to a standalone keyboard and mouse.

So I've been looking for solutions to have a nice Macbook-like keyboard and touchpad setup, and I came across the Surface Pro Signature cover, which looks like it might be exactly what I want (most other combos have the touchpad on the right side, I prefer it in the center).

But is it possible to use it with a (modern) Windows 10 desktop computer? I can't really find any reliable info on this topic. I would expect that it could be used with any bluetooth receiver and that Windows 10 would be able to load the correct drivers for it regardless of being connected to a Surface laptop or a desktop PC?

Answer (score 0):

It is a Bluetooth keyboard and touchpad.  Therefore it should connect to any Bluetooth enabled device.

I would also *highly* expect that Windows 10 will have no issues detecting the devices and installing the correct drivers.  It is a Microsoft product, after all.  Technically, it should work on any Bluetooth device as a standard keyboard and mouse.  Specific drivers and/or software would only be required for functionality *beyond* a standard keyboard.

Since I havent tried this myself, I cant say with 100% certainty.  However, there is no reason to think otherwise.  Heck, I can connect an original iPad keyboard to a Windows PC via Bluetooth, why wouldnt this work?

Comment: I agree, it definitely *should* work. I'm just suspicious since I couldn't find anyone who actually tried it or suggested it. I'm mostly worried that maybe multi touch and those kinds of things won't work. As you said it is a Microsoft product, not sure if that's a good or a bad thing though...

Comment: @MagnusW You can always contact Microsoft Sales and ask them.  If anyone would know, its them.

Comment: I contacted Microsoft on their chat, and their answer was very surprising - it's definitely NOT possible to use a Surface Cover with anything else than a Surface tablet/laptop! It turns out that it does not connect via Bluetooth, but rather via a hardware connector at the bottom/side of the Surface. Bummer, since I finally thought I'd found a good way to make my desktop PC at work feel less like a clumsy old Ford Model T and more like a sleek Tesla Model 3...

Comment: @MagnusW You might want to double check that.  I believe the older ones used the connector...  or perhaps the older ones used bluetooth